# c++ trie - every pointer points to null even after insertion

Tags: c++, pointers, trie

I'm trying to build a trie in c++ by implementing it through a B-Tree. Every single node has a key, an array of pointers to other nodes, and a boolean value determining if it's a leaf or not. By default, all pointers point to null when initializing a new node and whenever a new node is added, the previous node points to the new node.

But for some reason, my else if (currentNode.children[arrayPointer] != NULL) is never being called. I'm completely stumped. I'm not sure if it's because I'm labeling something wrong or if somethings not in the right order.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

numberOfWords = 0;
numberOfNodes = 0;

struct Node;
struct Node;
    struct Node {
    char key;
    bool isLeaf;
    struct Node *children[36]; //26 letters + 10 digits
};



main() {
    //initializing the root
    Node root;
    root.key ='$';
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 36) {
        root.children[i] = NULL;    
        i++;
    }
    root.isLeaf = 1;
    numberOfNodes++;

    insertWord("the", root);
    insertWord("and", root);
    insertWord("there", root);

    cout << numberOfWords << " words found." << endl;
    cout << numberOfNodes << " nodes found." << endl;

}

void insertWord(string word, Node currentNode) {
    int wordLength = word.length();
    char letterToInsert;
    letterToInsert = word[0];
    int arrayPointer;
    arrayPointer = charToInteger(letterToInsert);


    //if the node is not found, a new path is inserted
    if (currentNode.children[arrayPointer] == NULL) {
        insertNewPath(word, currentNode);
    }

    //if the node with the current letter is found, I want to recursively call
    //insertWord and pass in the updated word and the next node.    

    //For some reason, this statement is never being called.
    else if (currentNode.children[arrayPointer] != NULL)  {
        string updatedWord;
        updatedWord = word.substr(1,wordLength);
        Node nextNode;
        currentNode.children[arrayPointer] = &nextNode;
        insertWord(updatedWord, nextNode);
    }

}       

//This function will keep recursively calling itself and passing in the new word 
//and the new node until the each letter is added.
void insertNewPath(string word, Node currentNode) {
    int wordLength;
    wordLength = word.length();
    if (wordLength > 0) {
        char letterToInsert;
        letterToInsert = word[0];
        int arrayPointer;
        //charToInteger takes a character and converts it into an integer value - a=0,b=1,...,8=34,9=35
        arrayPointer = charToInteger(letterToInsert);
        Node newNode;
        numberOfNodes++;
        newNode.key = letterToInsert;
        // Here, I set the current node's pointer to point to the new node. 
        // This should cause line 168 to execute when entering an existing
        // letter to the trie but for some reason it never does.
        currentNode.children[arrayPointer] = &newNode;
        //setting every pointer in the new node to null
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 36) {
            newNode.children[i] = NULL; 
            i++;
        }
        currentNode.isLeaf = 0;
        string updatedWord;
        updatedWord = word.substr(1, wordLength);
        insertNewPath(updatedWord, newNode);
    }
    else if (wordLength == 0){
        currentNode.isLeaf = 1;
        //Once all the letters have been added, the last 
        //node/letter to be added is set as a leaf, making
        //it a complete word.
    }   
}
```

The output I'm expecting to get is

```
3 words found.
9 nodes found.
```

Instead I'm getting

```
3 words found.
11 nodes found.
```

So pretty much a node is being created for ever single letter.

Comment: Your code is too complicated. You can implement insert in at most 5-8 lines of code. The first step to simplify it is to define a constructor for Node that sets all the children to `nullptr`. Another hint, write a helper that takes arguments `(Node* root, const std::string& s, int index)`. Recursing is easy now. If your index is equal to the length of the string, you're done. Otherwise, ensure that the child you want to recurse to exists, and then do it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code has lots of other bugs in it, but in `insertNewPath`, `newNode` is allocated as an automatic (stack) local variable, meaning a pointer to it (`currentNode.children[arrayPointer] = &newNode;`) is not valid once execution leaves the block in which it was defined.

Comment: Adding to @ChristopherOicles. newNode runs out of scope after the function ends. So, the reference you pass in your argument makes your program point to random memory.